# Notificaciones Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-notifications, firebase-messaging

tengo el siguiente problema. Tengo un app que recibe notificaciones push de firebase. Hasta el momento excelente.

Cuando recibo la notificación lo que hago es crear una notificación de la siguiente manera:

```
private fun sendNotification(messageBody: String, title: String) {
        val intent =  Intent(this, NotificacionesActivity::class.java)
        intent.setClassName(this.packageName, "${this.packageName}.NotificacionesActivity")
        intent.putExtra("notificacion",true)
        intent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_INFO)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED

        //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)

        //val channelId:Int = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id)
        val defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)

        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, ""/*, channelId*/)

                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_mail)
                .setContentTitle(""+title)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build())
    }
```

Aquí suceden dos cosas interesantes:

1. Si la aplicación esta en primer plano y abro la notificación desde el gestor de notificaciones se abre perfectamente la actividad que requiero.
2. Si la aplicación esta en segundo plano y abro la notificación desde el gestor de notificaciones, se abre la actividad de Login que esta declarada como launcher en el manifiesto.

Lo que requiero es que suceda siempre la primera opción es decir que se abra la actividad NotificacionesActivity incluso si el app esta ejecutandose en segundo plano.

Es esto posible? Estaré olvidando alguna propiedad de las notificaciones y por eso no consigo el resultado esperado en ambos escenarios?

De antemano gracias.

Saludos.

Comment: quedo a la espectativa de esto que tambien me interesa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo logre resolver y el mismo no es el hecho de generar una notificación como tal en Android.

Cuando se genera una notificación push desde la consola de firebase, sucederan 2 escenarios posibles en el dispositivo una vez se reciba la información de la notificación.

**Escenario 1.** 
**La aplicación esta en segundo plano:** La notificación se recibe y se almacena en el centro de notificaciones.

**Escenario 2.**
**La aplicación en primer plano**: si implementamos como en mi caso un "service" que herede de `FirebaseMessagingService` en el método `onMessageReceived(...)` recibiremos la notificación push a su ves es ahí donde se ejecuta el método `sendNotification`.... En este caso se abrirá correctamente la actividad `NotificacionesActivity`

**Nota** la notificación en firebase en primera instancia la estuve armando de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el campo de "texto del mensaje" pensé incialmente que esto se recibe siempre en la aplicación pero realmente no es así para el escenario 1 donde la aplicación esta en segundo plano. Lo que quiero decir es que el texto del mensaje no llega a la aplicación si esta en segundo plano dado que la notificación se genera de manera automatica y se almacena en el centro de notificaciones.

Para resolver lo anterior, ajuste desde la consola las propiedades avanzadas de manera tal que si agrego parámetros estos datos si llegarán a la aplicación incluso si se encuentra en segundo plano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la parte que marque en rojo no necesariamente tiene que ir un mensajes o titulos de mensajes, ahí puede viajar información de cualquier tipo y se puede implementar cualquier funcionalidad sobre los mismos.

Con lo anterior, aunque el app se encuentre en segundo plano, y la notificación llegue directamente al centro de notificaciones de Android, al presionarla se abrirá la aplicación y los parámetros los podemos leer de de la siguiente manera:

```
if(getIntent()!=null)
            if (getIntent().getExtras()!=null)
                  if(getIntent().getExtras().containsKey("Cuerpo_Mensaje")) {

                    String mensaje = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Cuerpo_Mensaje");
                    String titulo = "";
                    if (getIntent().getExtras().containsKey("Titulo_Mensaje"))
                        titulo = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Titulo_Mensaje");
}
```

Posteriormente en mi caso decidí guardar la notificación en una base de datos local y mostrarla en la actividad de notificaciones.

La información del intent llegará a la actividad que este declarada como launcher en el manifiesto por lo que es ahí donde tienen que leer los extras.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba cambiando

```
 //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
```

a

```
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
```

mira el cambio el flag que se usa.

Comment: ok déjame probarlo y te aviso (y)

Comment: Jhon, puedes explicar porque el cambio?